# axis and shape in spyder variable explorer

Tags: spyder, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3 dimensional ndarray and cannot understand the Axis and Shape in the variable explorer of Spyder. 
Below variable is my 3 dimensional array and I would appreciate if someone can explan the axis and shapes for me:

```
t = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
t = np.reshape(t,(4,3,2))
```

[image: variable explorer]

for example when I set the Axis to 0, a 3*2 frame will show up. when I set it to 1, a 4*2 frame will show up and finally when I set the Axis to 2, a 4*3 frame will show up and I am having trouble visualizing them in a 3 dimensional form.
PS: I know it sounds completely unprofessional ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Axis 0 would list values on y-z plane
Axis 1 gives x-z plane values
Axis 2 would list values on x-y plane

Index would be the dimension of the third axis whose value is not shown for a given axis.

```
 a=np.ones(90)
 a = np.ones(90)
 a= a.reshape(9,5,2)
 a[0]=2*a[0]
 a[:,1,:]=3*a[:,1,:]
 a[:,:,1]=7*a[:,:,1]
 a.shape
```

Try this code and see the results with different values. If any index in slicing is -1, it means the value for that index is calculated based on the othee dimensions of the dataframe.